# Swift Firebase - Combining estimated ServerTimestamp with Codable Custom Objects

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, codable

I have a messaging app, where I have a `Chats` collection in my Firebase Firestore database.  I use a custom object which is Codable to read and write changes to firebase.

```
struct ChatFirebaseDO: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    
    ... {100 other fields} ...
    
    var lastMessageDate: Date
}
```

When a user sends a new message, I update this `lastMessageDate` with the `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

I also have a listener which is listening for changes, and it immediately returns any update to me (wnether that is a new Chat of an update to an existing one).  However if it is my own user that has created this new chat, it will be returned to me with a `null` timestamp.

From the docs I see this is intentional behaviour.  It suggests that I change replace the nulls with estimated timestamps values (perfect!) however, I can't work out how to combine this with my custom objects.

To get the estimated timestamps, I need to do this:
`diff.document.data(with: .estimate)`
which returns a dictionary of fields.

But for my `Codable` custom objects to work, I have to use:
`let messageDO = try diff.document.data(as: ChatFirebaseDO.self)`
which uses a document (not a dictionary of data).

**Is there a way I can (1) replace the nulls with estimated timestamps but (2) still have a document object I can use for my custom object transformation.**

Perhaps its a global setting I can make to use estimates, or locally within a single listener request.  Or perhaps it is a way to use custom objects from a data dictionary and not just from the `FIRDocument`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Firestore aside, is it a requirement that your structures be `Codable`?

Comment: Not a requirement, but its very helpful and "part of the furniture" in the architecture of my project.  It would be a shame to lose it just because of a single null timestamp from Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not encoding these chats for disk storage then why are they even `Codable` is a question to ask yourself. This particular method is made for that purpose so I'd argue you're using the wrong tool for the job—a tool that also doesn't work because of the timestamp conflict, which I imagine will be addressed in a future update to Firestore.

That said, the timestamps (which are tokens) only return `nil` when they haven't reached the server which means only from latency-compensated snapshots generated by the client (or only when the signed-in user posts). Therefore, you can provide your own estimate when the value is `nil` (which would be the current date and time), which would not only be accurate but would be overwritten by the subsequent snapshot anyway when it has a real value. It's not a pleasant workaround but it accomplishes exactly what the token does with its own estimate.

If you don't want to ditch `Codable` then you can ditch Firestore's timestamp, which I've personally done. I'm not a fan of the token system and I've replaced it with a basic Unix Timestamp (an integer) that makes things much simpler. I don't have to worry about `nil` times, latency-compensated returns, or configuring snapshot data just to handle the value of a single field. If I had to guess, I would imagine Firestore will eventually allow a global setting of timestamp behavior in addition to expanding the API to allow the `Codable` method to also account for timestamp behavior. The TLDR of it is that what you want doesn't yet exist natively in the Firestore SDK, unfortunately, and I'd consider making it a feature request on the Firestore-iOS git repo.